# Can I add enable colors when calling Google Test from Buck?

Tags: c++, googletest, buck

I find the output of `buck test` difficult to read. Google Test supports color output by adding the flag `--gtest_color=yes` when running the executable.

Is there a way to pass this flag through Buck to Google Test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could run the binaries manually with the [`buck run`](https://buckbuild.com/command/run.html) command and pass the argument there.